# error: incomparable types: double and <null>

Tags: java, null, double

My code gives me this error:

> error: incomparable types: double and .

I have no clue why.

This is what I want to do:

I have a formule (who gives me a double) but if this formule gives me no answer (divide by zero, ... ) I want to print : No answer!

beta & alfa are 2 doubles, you can choose.

```
double valueOne = valueOne(alfa,beta);  
double valueTwo = valueTwo(alfa,beta);  
public double valueOne(double alfa, double beta)
{
   return (-(Math.sqrt((-beta)/alfa)))+alfa;
}
public double valueTwo(double alfa, double beta)
{
    return (Math.sqrt((-beta)/alfa))+alfa;
}

if(valueOne == null && valueTwo == null)
{
    System.out.println("No values");
}
```

Comment: What result do you expect from comparing double and nothing? What result is of any comparison of anything with nothing?

Comment: `if(valueOne == null && valueTwo == null){` where is this written ? what is `valueOne` and `valueTwo`'s type

Comment: it was just a fragment of my code, i completed it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing a `double` to a `null` is of course illegal because the first one is a value type and value types are never `null` for which the `null` stands when comparing to reference types. This page might help you to distinguish the two: [What’s the difference between a primitive type and a class type in Java?](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/)

If you don't want to throw exceptions on invalid values or results your method could make use of the `Double.NaN` constnt field:

```
public double valueOne(double alfa, double beta)
{
    // At least one of the values is invalid.
    if (Double.isNaN((alfa) || Double.isNaN((beta))
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    // Check the alpha or otherwise a div/0 exception may be thrown.
    if (alfa == 0.0)
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    double divResult = (-beta)/alfa;

    // Check the div result because Math.sqrt accepts only positive values:
    // If the argument is NaN or less than zero, the result is NaN. 
    if (divResult < 0.0)
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    return (-(Math.sqrt(divResult)))+alfa;
}

double resultValueOne = valueOne(alfa, beta);  
if(Double.isNaN((resultOne))
{
    System.out.println("No resultValueOne");
}
```

[Sample at ideone](http://ideone.com/cJQN9T)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood a few things here.

1. you don't seem to be calling your two methods - I assume you mean something like valueOne(1, 2)
2. If your calculation gets an error (such as divide by zero) it doesn't return null, it throws an ArithmeticException
3. Therefore you shouldn't be comparing to null you should use a try catch block to handle errors
4. you can't compare an atomic type like double to null; only references to objects can be compared to null

Answer (score 0):

you can use string manipulation since java does not allow a primitive type to have null values.
if the string is empty , no values will appear. i hope this helps.

```
     public static void main(String []args){
    if(valueOne(0,0).equals("") && valueTwo(0,0).equals(""))
        System.out.println("No values");
    else
        System.out.println("val1:"+valueOne(0,0)+"val2:"+valueTwo(0,0));

     }
     public static String valueOne(double alfa, double beta){
        return ""+(-(Math.sqrt((-beta)/alfa)))+alfa;;
    }
public static String valueTwo(double alfa, double beta){
        return ""+(-(Math.sqrt((-beta)/alfa)))+alfa;;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this:

```
public double[] myMethod(double vAlfa, double vBeta, double wAlfa, double wBeta) {
    double[] answers = new double[2];
    try {
        answers[0] =  (-(Math.sqrt((-vBeta) / vAlfa))) + vAlfa;
        answers[1] =  (Math.sqrt((-wBeta)/wAlfa)) + wAlfa;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No values");
    }
    return answers;
}
```

This method returns the result of processes as an array of doubles (because you have two values).

In the `try` block, we try to calculate the answers and put them in the array.
and in the `catch` block, we deal with every exceptions (`NullPointerException` or `DivisionByZero` or ...) by an call to `System.println();` to print the given string for us.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's a very bad habit to use a try/catch in situations like this. You should check the parameters and not just catch everything.

Comment: @t3chb0t Certainly, you are right and I never code like this. But here it seems the one who asked question is seeking for some shortو understandable and sufficient answer, so I tried to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

First of all both `valueOne` and `valueTwo` are methods but you try to refer to them as variables (?!):

```
if(valueOne == null && valueTwo == null){
```

Second, anyway the return type of these methods and (if you define variables of the same type) is `double` that is  a primitive and cannot be `null`. `null` is a special value that can be used with object references only.

Take some java tutorial that explains java types for the beginning.

Comment: As strage as it is this is legal and it works, see the sample: http://ideone.com/nMYWLg

Comment: What legal and what works? Primitive cannot be null. Your example demonstrates usage of primitives and does not use null.

Comment: I refered to your first sentence that you couldn't use the same names for methods and variables. Correct me if I'm wrong and it's not what you meant.

Comment: I *can* use same names for variable and method. However code posted by OP did not contain definition of variables. It by the way was edited later and now has correct definition of the variables.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't know that you've answerd to the very first version of the question. _edit your answer so that I can remove the downvote ;-)_ - I think it's a pitty that there is no notification when the answer got edited but it's a topic for meta.